# JSP & Java - Present data in JSP using jslt forEach - How to access lower elements

Tags: java, spring, list, jsp, foreach

I have a task to do, I need to take data that has been returned in a response object, and I am sending that to a JSP. What I need to do, is to present this in a menu list that I have created using javascript and jquery - ( which works fine, it just needs the data).

I am using Spring, Here is my Java code - This shows the object:

```
@Controller
public class WordListController {

    /* @version $Revision: $ $Date: $ */

    @Autowired
    private FrontendServiceFacade FrontendServiceFacade;

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping("/ViewWords")
    public String WordListRequestController(Model model) {

        WordListRequest request = new WordListRequest();
        WordListResponse response;

        request.setLibraryId("LIB_CODE_1");

        try{
            response = (WordListResponse)FrontendFacade.getWordList(request);           
        }catch(Exception e){
            //TODO Process Exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        List<UserBooksType.Book> returnedWordBooks = null;
        List<UserBookPagesType.Page> returnedWordPages = null;
        List<WordsType.Word> returnedWords = null;
        List<WordPageList> WordPageList= new ArrayList<WordPageList>();

        int bookSize = 0;
        int pageSize = 0;
        int wordSize = 0;
        String bookId = "";
        String pageName = "";
        String wordId = "";

        returnedWordBooks = response.getDataLoad().getUserBooks().getBook();
        bookSize = response.getPayLoad().getUserBooks().getBook().size();

        WordPagesList wordPagesList = new WordPagesList();

        ArrayList<BookList> bookList = new ArrayList<BookList>();
        ArrayList<PageList> pageList = new ArrayList<PageList>();
        ArrayList<WordList> wordList = new ArrayList<WordList>();

        // Loop <Book>
        for (UserBooksType.Book book : returnedWordBooks) {
            System.out.println("Book Loop");

            bookId = book.getBookId();

            // *********************************************
            BookList bookL = new BookList();
            bookL.setBookId(bookId);
            // *********************************************

            returnedWordPages = book.getUserBookPages().getPage();
            pageSize = book.getUserBookPages().getPage().size();

            // Loop <Pages>
            for (UserBookPagesType.Page page : returnedWordPages) {

                pageName = page.getName();

                returnedWords = page.getWords().getWord();
                wordSize = page.getWords().getWord().size();

                // Loop <Word>
                for (WordsType.Word word : returnedWords) {
                    System.out.println("Word Loop");

                    wordId = word.getWordId();

                    WordPageList WordPage = new WordPageList();

                    WordPage.setBookId(bookId);
                    WordPage.setPageName(pageName);
                    WordPage.setWordId(wordId);

                    WordPageList.add(WordPage);

                }

            }
        }
        // model.addAttribute("ViewWords", WordPageList); // I dont want to pass
        model.addAttribute("ViewWords", response); // I want to pass this
        return "ViewWords";
    }

}
```

This shows how the object is build. What I would like to do is pass the "response" object directly to the JSP, and not the "WordPageList" List.

Is there a way I can pass this Object directly, and they cycle through the object on the JSP.

This is my JSP code:

```
<li ><span class="folder">Books</span>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="${ViewBooks}" var="WordPageList" varStatus="status">
            <li class="closed"><span class="folder">${WordPageList.bookId}</span>
                <ul>
                    <li class="closed"><span class="folder">${WordPageList.PageName}<br /></span>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="closed"><span class="folder">${WordPageList.wordId}<br /></span>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><span class="file">Option 1</span></li>
                                    <li><span class="file">Optoin 2</span></li>
                                    <li><span class="file">Option 3</span></li>
                                    <li><span class="file">Option 4</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This doesn't really work for what I want. I want to do something similar, but to pass the "response" object to the JSP and then cycle through this object to present the data, so I think this is using nested foreach statements, but I dont know how to do this, or how to assess these emements.

I hope this makes sense.

Edited:

This is the WordListResponse class as requested:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.CollapsedStringAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "responseStatus",
    "errorNumber",
    "errorDescription",
    "data"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "WordListResponse")
public class WordListResponse {

    protected int responseStatus;
    protected int errorNumber;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CollapsedStringAdapter.class)
    protected String errorDescription;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected WordListResponse.Data data;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the responseStatus property.
     * 
     */
    public int getResponseStatus() {
    return responseStatus;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the responseStatus property.
     * 
     */
    public void setResponseStatus(int value) {
    this.responseStatus = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the errorNumber property.
     * 
     */
    public int getErrorNumber() {
    return errorNumber;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the errorNumber property.
     * 
     */
    public void setErrorNumber(int value) {
    this.errorNumber = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the errorDescription property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getErrorDescription() {
    return errorDescription;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the errorDescription property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setErrorDescription(String value) {
    this.errorDescription = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the data property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link WordListResponse.Data }
     *     
     */
    public WordListResponse.Data getData() {
    return data;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the data property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link WordListResponse.Data }
     *     
     */
    public void setData(WordListResponse.Data value) {
    this.data = value;
    }


    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "userBooks"
    })
    public static class Data {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected UserBooksType userBooks;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the userBooks property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link UserBooksType }
     *     
     */
    public UserBooksType getUserBooks() {
        return userBooks;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the userBooks property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link UserBooksType }
     *     
     */
    public void setUserBooks(UserBooksType value) {
        this.userBooks = value;
    }

    }

}
```

Comment: what is the structure of `WordListResponse ` ?

Comment: Hi @JigarJoshi I have added the WordListResponse class now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested forEach works exactly as a non-nested forEach:

```
<%-- iterate over the someList field of the someObject attribute --%>
<c:forEach var="outerItem" items="${someObject.someList}">
    <%-- now, outerItem is an attribute, and you may access its fields --%>

    <%-- iterate over the otherList field of the outerItem attribute --%>
    <c:forEach var="innerItem" items="${outerItem.otherList}">

        <%-- now, innerItem is an attribute, and you may access its fields --%>

    </c:forEach>

</c:forEach>
```

The above supposes that the Spring controller stores an object with the following structure in the `someObject` attribute:

```
 class Xxx {
     public List<Yyy> getSomeList() {
         ...
     } 
 }

 class Yyy {
     public List<Zzz> getOtherList() {
         ...
     } 
 }
```

Comment: @JigarJoshi Do you know how I can access the following:     "responseStatus", 
    "errorNumber", 
    "errorDescription" variables in the JSP c: concept?

Comment: Do you know how I can access the following: "responseStatus", "errorNumber", "errorDescription" variables in the JSP c: concept which are not inside a list, but at the top level on the response object?

Comment: If the attribute name is `someObject`, then you access one of its property using `${someObject.someAttribute}`. So in your case: `${ViewWords.responseStatus}`.